# MS Access Form filter dropdown

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Having created a copy of an Access DB Backend in SQL Server, the Access Frontend has stopped showing the "Filter" list when the Filter button is pressed on the main form:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I'm not sure what is causing this. In the old frontend I am opening the form like this:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

Where sSQL is like:`sSQL= "Select * from [EventReport]"`

And in the new version I'm opening the form like this:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges)
```

I'm not sure if any of this is actually relevant to the issue, by any help is appreciated!

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit more googling found the answer. In Access Options I needed to turn on the ODBC Fields in the Filter Lookup options for the Current Database

[image]

Comment: Funky. I never noticed this different behavior.